# System.out.println() before getting input from the user

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();

        input.next();

    }
}
```

How can I get input from the user without System.out.println() line?

Comment: You don't need to `System.out.println`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the console doesn't appear without it. I use eclipse.

Comment: You can input data without System.out.println(), but in command line you aren't able to perceive the change of your program.

Comment: That's because you are running from within an IDE. Presumably that's a "feature". Nothing to do with Java.

Comment: If you are having trouble with the Console not showing up in Eclipse, you can manually open it. Window -> Show View -> Console

Answer (score 1):

You can either use System.in.read(); but the problem is with IDE, not with java. You can manually open it in Eclipse. Window -> Show View -> Console.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need System.out.println line, you need to configure your IDE to show the console and you need to store the input you get from the user in a variable like, 
String inputFromUser = input.next(), now the 'inputFromUser'will hold the input which user will enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;     

public class Foo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
            String text = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(text); 
        } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

initialize a variable first.. So you can save the input in it.. 
for example int x = input.nextInt();
   System.out.print() is just for printing on screen.